# akka.persistence.RecoveryTimedOut: Recovery timed out, didn't get snapshot within 30000 milliseconds

Tags: akka, akka-persistence

I have a failing test because of the timeout. Here's what I see in log output:

```
2018-05-15 10:47:56.152 WARN  com.datastax.driver.core.NettyUtil [UserDataServiceSpec-cassandra-plugin-default-dispatcher-27] [] [] - Found Netty's native epoll transport, but not running on linux-based operating system. Using NIO instead.
2018-05-15 10:48:38.616 ERROR n.f.c.indexing.UniquelyIndexingActor [UserDataServiceSpec-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-39] [UserDataServiceSpec-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-29] [akka.tcp://UserDataServiceSpec@127.0.0.1:51627/user/$c/user-email-indexer] - Persistence failure when replaying events for persistenceId [user-email-indexer]. Last known sequence number [0]
akka.persistence.RecoveryTimedOut: Recovery timed out, didn't get snapshot within 30000 milliseconds
2018-05-15 10:48:38.617 ERROR a.c.sharding.PersistentShardCoordinator [UserDataServiceSpec-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-39] [UserDataServiceSpec-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-30] [akka.tcp://UserDataServiceSpec@127.0.0.1:51627/system/sharding/userdataCoordinator/singleton/coordinator] - Persistence failure when replaying events for persistenceId [/sharding/userdataCoordinator]. Last known sequence number [0]
akka.persistence.RecoveryTimedOut: Recovery timed out, didn't get snapshot within 30000 milliseconds
2018-05-15 10:48:38.618 INFO  akka.actor.LocalActorRef [UserDataServiceSpec-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-39] [UserDataServiceSpec-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-35] [akka://UserDataServiceSpec/user/$c/user-email-indexer] - Message [akka.persistence.SnapshotProtocol$LoadSnapshotFailed] from Actor[akka://UserDataServiceSpec/system/cassandra-snapshot-store#-750137778] to Actor[akka://UserDataServiceSpec/user/$c/user-email-indexer#1201357728] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
2018-05-15 10:48:38.619 INFO  akka.actor.LocalActorRef [UserDataServiceSpec-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-37] [UserDataServiceSpec-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-39] [akka://UserDataServiceSpec/system/sharding/userdataCoordinator/singleton/coordinator] - Message [akka.cluster.sharding.ShardCoordinator$RebalanceTick$] from Actor[akka://UserDataServiceSpec/system/sharding/userdataCoordinator/singleton/coordinator#-75387958] to Actor[akka://UserDataServiceSpec/system/sharding/userdataCoordinator/singleton/coordinator#-75387958] was not delivered. [2] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
```

(Don't ask my why we are not using in memory storage to test persistent actors. It's not relevant to the problem right now.)

I am not experienced in Akka and JVM, but the messages I see are just the equivalence of "You screwed up, man". There is no hint in them how to fix the problem or why this `RecoveryTimedOut` occurs.

If someone could give me a valuable advice how to diagnose the problem, it would be nice.

`UniquelyIndexingActor` is created as cluster singleton.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your config:

```
akka {
  persistence {
    journal-plugin-fallback {
      recovery-event-timeout = 60s
    }
  }
}
```

It solved the problem for me. I found a reference to it in https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-persistence/src/main/resources/reference.conf